# Hostname overrided after Reboot even after making entry in /etc/hostname

Tags: linux, rhel, hostname

I have cloned a KVM vm from one host to other host, I tried to rename the hostname and it's been renamed. But after reboot still it goes to old name.
`hostnamectl command output
   Static hostname: new_name
Transient hostname: old_name
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm`

How do I find the root cause for this name change and what's the fix?

I'm using static IP and there's no hostname entry in `/etc/sysconfig/network` or in interfaces files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting Transient hostname: old_name and Static hostname: new_name. Then it's user space modification of hostname.

Make sure there's no entry for `Hostname` in 2 below files

```
1. ~/.bash_profile - for respective user
2. /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: Thanks there's Hostaname entry in rc.local file.

Answer (score -1):

What flavor of Linux?

Some things for RHEL

Look in the following:

/etc/sysconfig/network (you already tried changing that)

/etc/hostname  (the hostname is usually set here for older systems.)

For newer RHEL 7 and I think 8 you probably have hostnamectl running which will reset the /etc/hostname settings on reboot.

Let us know it this helps any!

hostnamectl set-hostname name doesn't work?

Comment: I already did hostnmectl set-hostname and in /etc/hostname but after reboot it's changing as per in the output pasted above.